# Asking for a type's kind in Scala vs Haskell

Tags: scala, haskell, higher-kinded-types

When asking for the kind of `[Int]` and `[]` in Haskell I get:

```
Prelude> :k [Int]
[Int] :: *
Prelude> :k []
[] :: * -> *
```

which makes sense: the first one is a proper type and the second one is a higher kinded type.

But when I do the same in Scala:

```
scala> :k -v List[Int]
scala.collection.immutable.List's kind is F[+A]
* -(+)-> *
This is a type constructor: a 1st-order-kinded type.

scala> :k -v List
scala.collection.immutable.List's kind is F[+A]
* -(+)-> *
This is a type constructor: a 1st-order-kinded type.
```

... it says both are higher kinded types. Why the first one isn't classified as a proper type? What's the reason for this difference?

Comment: it seems the first one just does not *see* the `int` (it talks just about `scala.collection.immutable.List` too

Answer (score 6):

It seems that `scala` sees the `[Int]` part in `List[Int]` perfectly well, but chooses to ignore it and always look at the "outer" type deliberately.

If this weren't true, then `type ListOfInt = List[Int]` followed by `:k -v ListOfInt` would yield `*` not `* -> *` but that's not the case:

```scala
scala> :k -v List
scala.collection.immutable.List's kind is F[+A]
* -(+)-> *
This is a type constructor: a 1st-order-kinded type.

scala> :k -v List[Int]
scala.collection.immutable.List's kind is F[+A]
* -(+)-> *
This is a type constructor: a 1st-order-kinded type.

scala> type ListOfInt = List[Int]
defined type alias ListOfInt

scala> :k -v ListOfInt
scala.collection.immutable.List's kind is F[+A]
* -(+)-> *
This is a type constructor: a 1st-order-kinded type.
```